# phonegap and android 2.x: Application Error: Is a directory(file:///#/ ... )

Tags: android, cordova

we're just about to launch our first app and are making pretty good progress as phonegap beginners so far. (At least imho)

We were testing it on Android 4.2+ so far and it's running fine. I was setting up an android emulator this morning to see how it works on 2.2 and 2.3.3 devices and was a bit shocked.
It's not working at all.

We're working with durandal as a SPA framework and as soon as I click on a menu item I'm getting the following error:

---

#### Application Error

Is a directory (file:///#/tasks)

[OK]

---

When I hit ok the app closes and that's it. Here's what I found in the log so far:

```
I/CordovaLog( 343): Found start page location: index.html
I/CordovaLog( 343): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
I/CordovaLog( 343): Found start page location: index.html
I/CordovaLog( 343): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/phonegap.js: Line 912 : Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing. Expected for Android 3.2 and lower only.
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/phonegap.js: Line 6725 : deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/phonegap.js: Line 6718 : Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/App/main-built.js: Line 22 : Debug mode enabled.
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/App/main-built.js: Line 22 : Starting Application
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 133 : init fired
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 133 : GA Plugin Success
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 133 : GA Plugin Track Page Success
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 133 : Device Name: undefined<br />Device Cordova: 2.9.0 JS=2.9.0-0-g83dc4bd<br />Device Platform: Android<br />Device UUID: xxx<br />Device Version: 2.3.3<br />
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/App/main-built.js: Line 22 : Started Application
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/App/main-built.js: Line 22 : [services/model] ,Validators created
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/App/main-built.js: Line 22 : [services/model] ,Validators registered
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/App/main-built.js: Line 22 : Activating,[object Object]
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/App/main-built.js: Line 22 : [services/datacontext] ,Entity saved
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/App/main-built.js: Line 22 : [services/model] ,Lesson validators applied,subject,timetable,dayOfWeek
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/App/main-built.js: Line 22 : [services/model] ,Settings validators applied,language
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/App/main-built.js: Line 22 : [services/model] ,Task validators applied,priority
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/App/main-built.js: Line 22 : [viewmodels/shell] ,Schulheld Loaded!
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/App/main-built.js: Line 22 : Activating Route,[object Object],[object Object],Sammy.Object: {"routeInfo": [object Object],"router": [object Object]}
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/App/main-built.js: Line 22 : Activating,[object Object]
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/App/main-built.js: Line 22 : Binding,views/shell,[object Object]
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/App/main-built.js: Line 22 : Binding,views/dashboard,[object Object]
D/CordovaLog( 343): file:///android_asset/www/App/main-built.js: Line 22 : Binding,views/nav,[object Object]
D/CordovaLog( 343): : Line 1 : exception firing destroy event from native
```

Does anyone on earth had a similar problem and maybe knows what causes this problem or how to solve this?